# GRUB2 Doesn't show Windows10 on SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have a problem with Grub2. I recently mounted an SSD on my computer with Windows 10. My HDD had dual boot installed in Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.10 LTS.
Then I decided to format my HDD, updating ubuntu, in order to have a system with:

-HDD Ubuntu 17.10

-SSD Windows 10.

After the update at the boot my Grub doesn't recognize Windows partition.
It shows only ubuntu's 17.10 entry, ubuntu recovery mode and memtest. I thought that the problem could be caused by the formatting of HDD which maybe contained the boot file for SSD.

Boot repair can't solve my problem because it can't find Windows boot file. I paste the report of command `fdisk -l`

> ```
> Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
>   Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
>   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
>   Disklabel type: dos
>   Disk identifier: 0x617803d7
> ```

```
  Dispositivo Avvio      Start       Fine    Settori   Size Id Tipo
  /dev/sda1   *           2048 1937051647 1937049600 923,7G 83 Linux
  /dev/sda2         1937053694 1953523711   16470018   7,9G  5 Esteso
  /dev/sda5         1937053696 1953523711   16470016   7,9G 82 Linux swap /Solari

  Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.


  Disk /dev/sdb: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
  Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disklabel type: dos
  Disk identifier: 0x561da74e

  Dispositivo Avvio     Start      Fine   Settori  Size Id Tipo
  /dev/sdb1   *          2048 232750363 232748316  111G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
  /dev/sdb2         232751104 234436607   1685504  823M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
```

How can I solve?? 
Thanks for all :)

Comment: Windows BIOS installs have a separate 100MB boot partition. You are not now showing that. But those boot files can be in main partition. If missing then you need a Windows repair disk as you cannot fix from Windows. Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair. And do not use Boot-Repair's auto fix. That just installs grub to both drives. You want grub on Ubuntu drive, but Windows boot loader on Windows drive. Then when Windows needs repairs, you may be able to directly boot it from BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I show you boot repair paste bin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NGX3HVMTGk/

Comment: You may have deleted the Windows boot. You do have Windows bootmgr in sdb1, but it is missing BCD. You need Windows repair disk or third party tools to recreate a BCD. Also install Windows boot loader to MBR of sdb drive, but keep grub boot loader in sda.

Comment: Ok thanks. So you suggest to run a Windows Live on USB to fix BCD?